# How can I use jsPDF with angular 7.2 to export component html of dynamic data into a PDF file?

Tags: json, angular, jspdf

I have jsPDF, html2canvas installed and imported those libraries ina component.

On clicking a button, it triggers to a function which is supposed to export a html file to a PDF file. But it is not working.

Also, how can I use jsPDF to load an html file with dynamic data that I get from an API and download it into a PDF file?

Here are the codes:
 - jspdf.component.html

```
<div id="content" #content>

<div class="alert alert-info">
<strong>Html To PDF Conversion - Angular 7.2</strong>
</div>
<div>
<input type="button" value="CPTURE" (click)="captureScreen()"/> 
</div>
</div>
<div class="text-danger" id="contentToConvert">hi everyone</div>
```

- jspdf.component.ts

  ```
  import * as jspdf from 'jspdf'; 
  import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';  


  public captureScreen() {
    var data = document.getElementById('contentToConvert');
    html2canvas(data).then(canvas => {
    // Few necessary setting options  
      var imgWidth = 208;
      var pageHeight = 295;
      var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
      var heightLeft = imgHeight;


    const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
    let pdf = new jspdf('p', 'mm', 'a4'); // A4 size page of PDF  
    var position = 0;
    pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight)
    pdf.save('MYPdf.pdf'); // Generated PDF   
  });
  }
  ```
- On clicking Capture Screen button, the console shows the error `core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'className' of object '[object SVGSVGElement]'
  TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'className' of object '[object SVGSVGElement]'`

Comment: Show what you have done so far

Comment: I have installed `jspdf` and `html2canvas` first. Then, created a component jspdf.

Comment: Show the function

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
captureScreen() {

  var doc = new jsPDF();

  var content = document.getElementById('contentToConvert')

  html2canvas(content).then(canvas => {

    doc.addImage(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"), 'PNG', 15, 40, 180, 110);
    doc.save(`MYPdf.pdf`);

  });

}
```

Comment: Try this, if this works, other settings can be added later

Comment: No, it didn't work.
`core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'className' of object '[object SVGSVGElement]'
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'className' of object '[object SVGSVGElement]'`.

Comment: Please create a reproducable example in stackbiltz and share

Comment: It worked by changing the html2canvas version as `html2canvas@1.0.0-alpha.3`. Need to work on settings. Thanks for looking into it.